# instance fleet in emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

how to launch 6 core node emr cluster with 2 node from each family.

```
 [
  {
    "Name": "MasterFleet",
    "InstanceFleetType": "MASTER",
    "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
    "InstanceTypeConfigs": [{"InstanceType": "m4.xlarge"}]
  },
  {
    "Name": "CoreFleet",
    "InstanceFleetType": "CORE",
    "TargetSpotCapacity": 6,
    "LaunchSpecifications": {
     "SpotSpecification": {
        "TimeoutDurationMinutes": 10,
        "TimeoutAction": "SWITCH_TO_ON_DEMAND"
      }
    },
    "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
      {
        "InstanceType": "m4.large",
        "BidPrice": "0.1"
      },
      {
        "InstanceType": "m4.xlarge",
        "BidPrice": "0.2"
      },
      {
        "InstanceType": "m4.2xlarge",
        "BidPrice": "0.4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am passing above config.json file in my aws cli create cluster script.

```
aws emr create-cluster \
  --instance-fleets file://config.json
```

It allocates all instances from same family based on default allocation strategy "lowestPrice", how to pass property "diversified" to make it launch instances from different families ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks right except for capitalization: "Masterfleet" and "Corefleet" -- not "MasterFleet" and "CoreFleet".  Might want to check the others.